# How to get facebook feed with images and videos along with text?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to fetch logged user feeds within ios app, I have try with graph api that, graph api returns the data, its fine.
But when I have cross check the data to the actual facebook feed on facebook user page there are some problems found:

1. If post has text only than text coming on message key, along with post id,
2. If post has text with image/video only text coming on message key
3. And if post has only image/video than message key not coming.

I know message key is only for description/text but images? Is there any way to get the feed with whole content just same as appeared on facebook.

I have try below code:

**For Login**

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile", "user_posts"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("failed to start graph request: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
       // self.getPosts()//old
        self.getFBPost()
    }
```

**For getFBPost**

```
 func getFBPost() {
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/feed", parameters: nil)?.start(completionHandler: { (fbConnectionErr, result, error) in
       // print(fbConnectionErr)
        print(result)
        //print(error)
    })
}
```

**Coming response like this:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "https://medium.com/frame-io-engineering/huge-images-small-phone-15414b30d39e",
      "created_time": "2018-12-03T13:59:01+0000",
      "id": "68288174406_653966194"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2018-12-01T13:43:02+0000",
      "id": "68288174406_6528518443724"
    },
    {
      "message": "I love my Mom",
      "created_time": "2018-11-30T13:27:38+0000",
      "id": "68288174406_652289420323"
    }

}
```

as you can see the second post has only id and created time, while we check this on facebook page this the post with image, and third post has video but only text coming from graph api

Please guide whats wrong I did? Or What should I do to getting whole feed data in json formate just same as appeared on facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not asking for any fields in the API call, so you only get default ones. It is called "Declarative Fields" (`/me?fields=message,created_time,...`) and came with v2.4:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/archive#v2_4_new_features
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#reading

Comment: @luschin  can you please guide me by giving the sample of the declarative fields? How to add these and where to add?

Comment: i have added another link and a small example. you need to read the very basics of dealing with the graph api first.

Comment: Ok I have get the solution for this by reading your given link and some other searches. Sharing my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the give doc that are shared by @luschn. And got the solution I forgot the declarative fields as @luschn suggest me, Now solution given below: Only need to change in the graph api,

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/feed", parameters: ["fields":"created_time,attachments,type,message"])?.start(completionHandler: { (fbConnectionErr, result, error) in
     print(fbConnectionErr)
     print(result)
     print(error)
        let re = result as? [String: Any]
        let data = re?["data"] as! [[String: Any]]
        for dict in data {
            print(dict)
        }
    })
```

**OR**
 If you have page id you can use below url to hit the get api.

https://graph.facebook.com/(api_version)/(page_id)?fields=feed{created_time,attachments,message}&access_token=(token_id)